# Oracle UCP: When to use destroyConnectionPool vs. stopConnectionPool

Tags: java, oracle, ucp

I've browsed the documentation but I can't find a satisfactory explanation of which scenarios are supposed to be used the two methods.

Which are the conditions that would guide me in choosing one over the other? What are the advantages or drawbacks?